# Why do values are shown/stored in an unsymmetrical way?

Tags: debugging, assembly, masm, tasm

I've written a little program for a college assignment that is about substracting a 1x3 `Vector` by the *second column* of a 3x7 `Matrix` and storing the result in a 1x3 `VectorR`.

I've already finished it getting the correct answer, but something really took my attention:

Using **Turbo Debugger** I noticed that the result in the *Data Segment* (hexadecimal values) was being stored (or maybe just displayed) differently than the result of the example my teacher gave:

**Teacher's result:**

[image: Teacher]

**My result:**

[image: Mine]

I know those are different results, but they are correct. I would expect the values to be stored in the following way (for example):

```
0103
04FD
0606
0A0A
0B0B
```

But it's stored like (for example)

```
0103
04FD06
06
0A0A
0B
0B
```

From what I know until now, the values between `ds:` and the values are memory directions, but I guess that they have the same length (32 bits for 32-bit architecture), but it seems like some have more/less length. Of course this is just my guess. So, my question is:

**Why are these values stored in that way? What does it mean to have, in some directions, values like `050908` and only `05` in others? Or... Is it a debugger dependent?**

**Edit:** This is the way `ds` looks at the start of the program:

[image: At the start]

- **Red:** Some variables
- **Yellow:** `Vector` values
- **Black:** `VectorR` values

Comment: You only have bytes in memory, no structure. The different printout is probably just a friendly service from your debugger, based on the debug information.

Comment: You are only _seeing_ the end result differently (why? Turbo debugger experts...go). The contents are the same - which you can verify by looking at the offsets to the left of the actual data.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis it makes sense. So, the values in the left `ds:xxxx` are memory addresses right?

Comment: @Christian: It certainly looks that way, I would guess so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But the sequence of hex numbers is the same. one is formatted in columns, the other according the instructions , which can be longer or shorter.  instructions with implicit or no addressing need less space than instructions with a following memory address. In the second case of formatting the list of instructions, the instruction length show, in the first case it doesn't. When loaded into RAM, it doesn't matter - all it matters then is that the sequence is still correct. Consider that the layout differs when presented to you - but memory is one-dimensional, as if all instructions were all written on one single line - which would be more difficult to read for you.

(Note: I talk about "instructions" above, due to the presented evidence having been only a small section of the dump, in sub-thumbnail format. It wasn't evident then that shown data are probably not instructions.)

Even though does the debugger try to make sense from data, formatting it such that it could be presented in a way that data belonging together is printed on same line. The debugger doesn't know, and goes for clues it derives from the data as it sees them. Therefore it's not warranted that data is layouted correctly. A debugger which doesn't try to read meaning into data won't fail there, of course. One clue a debugger could go for is "this is an opcode of a known instruction, therefore I layout it such that the number of bytes this instruction has is shown on one line". so yes, debugger specific.

Comment: So those values are instructions? Aren't they the values result of the operation I made? Since they are in the data segment `ds` I'd expect them to *"represent"* just data, not instructions.

Comment: The are the result of assembling or compiling the source code of your program into a machine-executable represenation, consisting of instructions and data.  An instruction is an opcode with - potentially - some data following. Not all instructions need data, for those there'd be only the opcde.  An example would be a NOP, a "no operation". On the other hand, an instruction which loads a  fixed value into a registrer, consists of the opcode of that instruction, followed by the value to load. It may be evident that the wider the register is, the longer the data will have to be.

Comment: data in data segment can get there several ways: either as part of your program, and the program loader placing them there, or as result of operation of the program, which stores data there. For more accurately telling what there is, one needs to see more than the few lines you put there.

Comment: I've edited the post with some information about where the values come from. My question is: Why sometimes there are 3 bytes in a row or 2 or 1? Is it debugger-dependent as MichaelFoukarakis commented?

Comment: In this case tries the debugger to make sense from data, formatting it such that it could be presented such that data belonging together is printed on same line. The debugger doesn't know, and goes for clues it derives from the data as it sees them. Therefore it's not warranted that data is layouted correctly. A debugger which doesn't try to read meaning into data won't fail there, of course. One clue a debugger could go for is "this is an opcode of a known instruction, therefore I layout it such that the number of bytes this instruction has is shown on one line". so yes, debugger specific.

Comment: It looks like the correct answer. Seeing at the two other columns in the debugger, it shows the opcode that corresponds to the *hex* values. So it seems like it is trying to get a meaning from those values and showing them in a *instruction-readable* way. Please, could you update your answer so I accept it?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at data in the code-section of Turbo Debugger. So the bytes will be arranged as machine instructions. Look at your whole TD:

[image: Turbo Debugger Screenshot]

You worked in the section top left, but the section for data is down left, where you see "ds:0000...". After executing the first two instructions it will be changed to "es:0000..." because the value of `DS` has been changed. Now click anywhere in that section or use `TAB` until the cursor blinks there, and press `CTRL-G`. Type in "DS:0" and the section shows you the values of the DS-segment again.

Comment: I accessed to the `ds` through: `File > Table reallocate... > ds`. Both, your way and mine shows exactly the same data. But in the way I accessed to `ds` it seems like the debugger rearrange it in a *instruction-readable* way (based on what @Bushmills said).